# how i solve error dxdbtrD14 bpl is missing

Tags: delphi-2010, bpl

Please help me with this problem.

This problem comes when I move my project to another PC. This program works fine on my PC.

[image: this is my screenshot for the error message]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your project configured to compile with [Runtime Packages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Runtime_Packages) enabled. That means for any standard, 3rd party, and custom packages that your project uses, you have to deploy their respective BPL files that your EXE depends on, in addition to the EXE itself.

A BPL is just a fancy DLL with built-in support for Delphi’s RTL and VCL/FMX frameworks. The error you are getting is a standard Windows error popup dialog when the OS loader can’t find a required DLL that an EXE is statically linked to.

To avoid the error, you need to either:

- deploy all required BPL file(s) along with your EXE. Use a tool like Dependency Walker to figure out what they are.
- [turn off the “Runtime Packages” option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Runtime_Packages_(Options)).  Your EXE will be much larger, but it will be more self-contained, as the relevant package code will be built into the EXE itself.